# Wrong implementation of nested interfaces in Golang

Tags: go, go-interface

I'm struggling to understand why the following code cannot be compiled:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A interface {
    Hello() B
}

type B interface {
    World()
}

type AStruct struct{}

func (a AStruct) Hello() BStruct { 
    return BStruct{}
}

type BStruct struct{}

func (b BStruct) World() {}

func build(a A) {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}

func main() {
    a := AStruct{}
    build(a)
}
```

The compilation error is:
`cannot use a (variable of type AStruct) as A value in argument to build: AStruct does not implement A (wrong type for method Hello) have Hello() BStruct want Hello() B`

If I change `func (a AStruct) Hello() B`, the error is gone. Shouldn't BStruct implement the B interface?

<< UPDATED CODE >>

How shall I modify the code if the interface definition and the methods are in different packages.

`packX.go`

```
package packX

import "fmt"
import "packY"

type A interface {
    Hello() B
}

type B interface {
    World()
}

func build(a A) {
    fmt.Println("hello")
}

func read() {
    a := packY.AStruct{}
    build(a)
}
```

and the packY.go

```
package packY

type AStruct struct{}

func (a AStruct) Hello() BStruct { 
    return BStruct{}
}

type BStruct struct{}

func (b BStruct) World() {}
```

If I change `func (a AStruct) Hello() BStruct` to `func (a AStruct) Hello() packX.B`, then I have circular import.

Comment: "I have circular import." then put `type B interface` definition in another file that both can import.  "If I change func (a AStruct) Hello() B, the error is gone. Shouldn't BStruct implement the B interface?"  As Burak Sendar explained, that isn't enough.  It has to return a `B`, not just anything that implements B.

Answer (score 2):

Go type system uses strict function signature matching: if an interface method is declared to return `B`, then a type method implementing that interface must return `B`, and not a type that implements `B`.

Comment: Thank Burak for the quick answer. I modified the code in the question. I'm still struggling to find a solution.

Comment: Make `AStruct.Hello` return `B`